# How to attach background process to systemctl service's CGroup

Tags: centos, systemd, forking

let me explain a little bit more.
I have a service on CentOS 7 that launches a sh script. The script then forks to let's say 4 other child processes. If one dies, I want to launch it from another service, but I want it attached to the other 3 processes' CGroups.

So systemctl status myService shows 4 processes (after the main script finishes forking into 4 children). Then if one child process is killed, systemctl status myService shows only 3 processes into CGroup. So how is it possible to launch the missing one and then attaching it to the other 3's CGroup, so that systemctl status myService shows 4 children again?

Example:

`Active: active (running)
CGroup: /system.slice/myService.service
        - 1234 process1
        - 1235 process2
        - 1237 process4`

`Active: active (running)
CGroup: /system.slice/myService.service
        - 1234 process1
        - 1235 process2
        - 1236 process3
        - 1237 process4`

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried cgexec? `man cgexec` - You may have to specify multiple controllers /paths (multiple `-g` switches) to replicate all cgroups. See `/proc/<PID>/cgroup` on the running service PID vs. the other service PID (or launched process) to see what needs to change.

Comment: I've tried `cgclassify -g *:/usr/lib/systemd/system/myService.service <PID>`, but I get  _Error changing cgroup of <PID>: Cgroup does not exist_
Seems I can't get the real path for the CGroup, even though systemctl is clear

Comment: No, you are confusing cgroup paths with unit file paths. Even though both end with ".service" they are not the same thing.

Comment: On top of that you probably won't have one path for all controllers. See what cgroups should be configured while the process is running and replicate that **exactly**. You may need up to one `-g` switch per line in the cgroups file in proc. Using cgexec to launch the process directly in the right cgroup is preferable but using cgclassify should lead to the same results as long as you include all threads and forks of that process.

Answer (score 0):

If you `cat "/proc/$pid/cgroup"` where `$pid` denotes PID of a process that belongs to `myService.service`, you will see something like:

```
10:memory:/
9:blkio:/
8:pids:/system.slice/myService.service
7:perf_event:/
6:net_cls,net_prio:/
5:freezer:/
4:devices:/system.slice/myService.service
3:cpuset:/
2:cpu,cpuacct:/
1:name=systemd:/system.slice/myService.service
```

The entry `name=systemd:/system.slice/myService.service` is crucial. To make `systemd` "assimilate" another process into the service, you need to replicate this entry.

Normally one would use `cgclassify` or `cgexec`. E.g. these work fine:

```
cgexec -g memory:/ -g pids:/system.slice/myService.service sleep 60 &
cgclassify -g cpuset:/ "$pid"
```

But I haven't found a way to make it work with `name=systemd:`. The following commands fail in my Debian 9:

```
cgexec -g  name=systemd:/system.slice/myService.service sleep 60
cgexec -g  systemd:/system.slice/myService.service      sleep 60
cgexec -g '*systemd:/system.slice/myService.service'    sleep 60
cgexec -g '*:/system.slice/myService.service'           sleep 60
```

Similar tries with `cgclassify` (for already started process) also fail. However instead of `cgclassify` you can do this:

```
echo "$pid" > /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/myService.service/tasks
```

Or if you need `sudo`:

```
echo "$pid" | sudo tee /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/myService.service/tasks
```

After this `$pid` will appear in the output of `systemctl status myService.service` and `systemd` will consider the process a part of the service (e.g. it will kill it if you invoke `systemctl stop myService.service`).

To mimic the original process you may need to replicate other entries. E.g. for `pids:/system.slice/myService.service` any of these two commands should work:

```
cgclassify -g pids:/system.slice/myService.service "$pid"
# or
echo "$pid" > /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/myService.service/tasks
```

---

Sometimes spawning a process and changing its cgroup(s) later may be sub-optimal. You may want the process to *start* in proper cgroups. Normally you would do this with `cgexec` but (as stated above) this seems not to work with `name=systemd:`. Possible approach:

```
sh -c '
  echo "$$" > /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/myService.service/tasks || exit 1
  cgclassify -g cpuset:/ -g devices:/system.slice/myService.service "$$" || exit 1
  # add more -g arguments if you need
  exec your_command with arguments
'
```

The trick is when the shell `exec`s to `sleep` it's in the right cgroups already. Or even:

```
sh -c '
  echo "$$" > /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/myService.service/tasks || exit 1
  exec cgexec -g cpuset:/ -g devices:/system.slice/myService.service your_command with arguments
  # add more -g arguments if you need
'
```

From within a script you may want to do it like this:

```
nohup sh -c ' … ' &
```